# Strange behaviour of Swiper JS scrollbar

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

When I set

```
loop: true,
scrollbar: { el: '.swiper-scrollbar' },
centeredSlides:true
```

as options for Swiper JS, the scrollbar is away from the left.

The behavior I'm expecting is the scrollbar to be in full left position on the first slide and fully right positioned on the last slide.

#### Demo

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView:5,
  centeredSlides:true,
  loop:true,
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 1<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 2<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 3<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 4<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 5<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 6<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 7<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 8<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 9<br><br><br></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><br><br><br>Slide 10<br><br><br></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/5.4.5/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

- https://codepen.io/pen/rNeGKrB

Answer (score 5):

> "It is by design. The scrollbar is `not` supported with loop mode"

(swiper official answer). Read under this Github Issue: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2315

Also the `centeredSlides:true` not working well combine with `.swiper-scrollbar`

### Support setting (True to Sep 20)

You should use the `centeredSlides:false` & `loop:false`.

```js
/* Support setting */
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView:5,
  centeredSlides:false,
  loop:false,
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  }
});
```

SUM: **No way** to solve/answer this (You could open GitHub issue/feature-request her: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues).

#### Working example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView:3,
  centeredSlides:false,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  loop:false,
  grabCursor: true,
  scrollbar: {
    el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

- Demo: https://swiperjs.com/demos/#scrollbar
- API docs: https://swiperjs.com/api/#scrollbar

Comment: "it is by design", why would they design it like that? Scrollbar + loop would be great...